# What simple and rules-light system can be used to play WH40k?

Tags: game-recommendation, warhammer-40k

I want to play a game set in the WH40k universe, where we play as Space Marines. Too bad that DEATHWATCH and WH40k for d20 are too rules-heavy and my players won't read that. It must be really lite: less than 40 pages.

Also I'd like a system with a highly lethal combat system and I'd prefer a system that encourages storytelling and description rather than a system that is just "hack n slash". What system can I use?

Comment: When you say light, how light do you mean? Less than 200 pages? Less than 50? Less than 10?

Comment: The question as it is is probably too broad. What are you looking for in this system, apart from a setting and lean rules? Which themes do you want to explore? Where's the focus of your ideal game?

Comment: I added some information. Is it ok?

Comment: Not enough for an answer, as I haven't used it, but there are a couple of hacks in progress for [Rogue Trader/Apocalypse World](http://apocalypse-world.com/forums/index.php?board=21.0) and [Deathwatch/Apocalypse World](http://story-games.com/forums/discussion/18481/making-a-deathwatchapocalypse-world-hack/p1)

Comment: There are thousands of systems that could be used for this, which means your question suffers from [a common problem we've identified](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/how-to-deal-with-questions-that-just-dont-understand-the-scope-of-the-rpg-lands) where it innocently assumes that there are way, way fewer RPGs in existence than there actually are. Right now, this won't get good answers, only suggestions for people's favourite systems out of those thousands that match your description. Pick any of the many light generic RPGs.